# Fillter data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

**Find data from array.**

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2000
            [rating] => 5
            [length] => 89
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2000
            [rating] => 5
            [length] => 80   
   )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2000
            [rating] => 1
            [length] => 105 
       )
   [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2000
            [rating] => 5
            [length] => 90 
    )

   [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2001
            [rating] => 4
            [length] => 55 
    )
  [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2001
            [rating] => 3
            [length] => 55 
    )
)
```

Required condition if id is the same:

1. get record which have max rating.
2. If rating is same in array, then get result base on length(max Length)

Required Output :

```
array(
   [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2000
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 90 
   )
  [4] => Array
   (
        [id] => 2001
        [rating] => 4
        [length] => 55 
 )
)
```

Comment: Show your current code. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `usort` and simple `foreach` loop like as

```
usort($arr,function($a,$b){
    $c = $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
    $c .= $b['length'] - $a['length'];
    return $c;
});
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(!isset($result[$value['id']])){
        $result[$value['id']] = $value;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

*(I thinck you should reformulate your question, it's very messy...)*

Maybe you could thinck of using a foreach() if you have to sort.

```
//$max = 0;
foreach( $arrayWithSameIds as $key => $element){

  if($element['rating'] > $max){ 
    //$max = $element;
  }else if($element['rating'] == $max){
    //compare $max['length'] and $element['length']
  }else{

  }
```

}

I'm not shure of what you're looking for ...